# Python turtle class compute length

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am making some kind of a ripoff of turtle module for drawing.

This is what i have so far:

```
class Turtle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = drawer.maxX / 2
        self.y = drawer.maxY / 2
        self.angle = 0
        self.pen_active = True
        self.pause = 0
        self.body = drawer.circle(0, 0, 5, drawer.green, 3)
        self.head = drawer.circle(0, 0, 3, drawer.green, 3)
        self.length = 0
        self.update()

    def set_pause(self, n):
        self.pause = n

    def no_pause(self):
        self.set_pause(0)

    def hide(self):
        self.body.hide()
        self.head.hide()

    def show(self):
        self.body.show()
        self.head.show()

    def update(self):
        self.body.setPos(self.x, self.y)
        phi = radians(90 - self.angle)
        self.head.setPos(self.x + 5 * cos(phi), self.y + 5 * sin(phi))
        drawer.wait(self.pause)

    def pen_up(self):
        self.pen_active = False

    def pen_down(self):
        self.pen_active = True

    def fly(self, x, y, angle):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.angle = angle
        self.update()

    def forward(self, a):
        phi = radians(90 - self.angle)
        nx = self.x + a * cos(phi)
        ny = self.y + a * sin(phi)
        if self.pen_active:
            drawer.line(self.x, self.y, nx, ny)
        self.x = nx
        self.y = ny
        self.update()

    def backward(self, a):
        self.forward(-a)

    def turn(self, phi):
        self.angle += phi
        self.update()

    def left(self):
        self.turn(-90)

    def right(self):
        self.turn(90)

    def length(self):
        pass
```

Now i am trying to write a method to compute the length of the line drawn but i don't know how to do it. The line is drawn when the pen is down and the turtle is going forwards or backwards. If the turtle flys or turns around the line is not drawn. Any ideas.

And thank your for all your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem does this help?

Comment: More specifically, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Euclidean_distance_in_various_coordinate_systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to maintain a record of the length of all the `forward` and `backward` movements your `Turtle` makes from the time it is created.

This is pretty easy, you just need to be a bit careful with your variable names. Currently you're using `length` both as an instance variable (to hold the running length sum) and as a method name. The former will shadow the latter, so you probably want two different names.

If we rename the instance variable to `_length`, you can make it work like this:

```
class Turtle:
    def __init__(self):
        # unmodified stuff omitted

        self._length = 0

    # unmodified methods skipped

    def forward(self, a):
        # all the current stuff

        self._length += abs(a) # absolute value to count backing up as movement

    def length():
        return self._length
```

You may decide you don't need the trivial `length` method, in which case you can go back to using `self.length` as your instance variable name (and just access the attribute when you want the value).